# Viewing Firebase storage pdf file in webview

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I'm trying to show a PDF file saved in Firebase storage using a webview. But the view I'm receiving is blank and grayish at the top only.

```
public class PerformanceFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView webView;
    private String postUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sas-android-73b28.appspot.com/o/sequence.pdf?alt=media&token=9fc1de4e-1059-4b2b-865e-1c44453a7eb8";



    public PerformanceFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_performance, container, false);


        webView =  root.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + postUrl);

        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                getActivity().setTitle("Loading...");
                getActivity().setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });


            return root;
    }


}
```

fragment_performance.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".PerformanceFragment">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I'm authenticated and yet nothing else is shown.Screenshot is given below: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSRFa.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: check this answer, maybe can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810673/open-firebase-storage-pdf-url-in-webview/67382790#67382790

Answer (score 5):

```
 final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setTitle("Course PDF");
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    webView=view.findViewById(R.id.pdfviewr);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    String url="";
    String pdf = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mindlabz-6f809.appspot.com/o/course_content%2FCracking%20the%20Coding%20Interview.pdf?alt=media&token=12a7fb3d-92d8-49f6-bd13-f88ec634c06c";
    try {
        url=URLEncoder.encode(pdf,"UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="+url);
    return view;
}
```

**Just Try This code**

URL Convert to UTF-8 And it works to load from firebase also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
WebView wv = root.findViewById(R.id.webView);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
wv.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + postUrl);
```

and you can use show progress bar as it might take time to load the pdf.

Comment: Nope still nothing.With no connection,it is showing proper error but with connection not the content from the url.

Comment: I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(88)] "Uncaught CustomError: Did not receive drive#about kind when fetching import map:undefined", source: http://www.gstatic.com/_/apps-viewer/_/js/k=apps-viewer.standalone.en_US.WVTrycVKBfk.O/rt=j/d=1/rs=AC2dHMILv9olQyExeqJTQgrPdHWt3CcrVQ/m=main